# SQLLDR and skip_unusable_indexes

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a table with a Unique Index that I need to load 800,000 rows into.

I altered the index and made it unuseable. 
I added 'options( rows=4000, bindsize=512000, skip_unusable_indexes=TRUE )' to my control file.

I'm still getting errors of the form:

```
ORA-01502: index 'x_Unique' or partition of such index is in unusable state
```

Suggestions welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do it with unique indexes. See [SKIP_UNUSABLE_INDEXES](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96652/ch04.htm#1005638):

> However, indexes that are unique and marked IU are not allowed
>   to skip index maintenance. This rule is enforced by DML operations,
>   and enforced by the direct path load to be consistent with DML.

You probably should drop your index and recreate it after.

Comment: Thanks missed that little tidbit, Will drop at re-add after the load

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could replace the unique index with a non-unique index and then place a unique constraint on the same column(s). Then the constraint can be disabled and the index made unusable before the load, then the index rebuilt and the constraint re-enabled afterwards.